# each on a class inside a parent class

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="busket ">            
             <button id="buybtn" class="btn btn-success" href="#OrderModal" data-toggle="modal" name="id" data-id=",1,2" data-quantity=",1,1"><span class="icon16  icomoon-icon-checkmark-2"></span>Buy</button>  

            <div class="form-row row-fluid" id="addeditem1"><div class="cpan12"><div class="span4"> <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><input class="spinner1 ui-spinner-input" id="addedq1" value="1" min="1" name="value" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="1" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton"><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span></span></a><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span></span></a></span></div></div><div class="span6"><img class="addedimg" src="/amrajegeachi18/productImages/small/1.png"></div><div class="span2"><span class="icon12 remove-item icomoon-icon-cancel" id="1"></span></div></div><div class="form-row row-fluid" id="addeditem2"><div class="cpan12"><div class="span4"> <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><input class="spinner1 ui-spinner-input" id="addedq2" value="1" min="1" name="value" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="1" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton"><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span></span></a><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span></span></a></span></div></div><div class="span6"><img class="addedimg" src="/amrajegeachi18/productImages/small/2.png"></div><div class="span2"><span class="icon12 remove-item icomoon-icon-cancel" id="2"></span></div></div></div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  $('.busket>.spinner1').each(function(){
          // var id = $(this).attr('id');
           alert('it works');
        });
```

there are lot of .spinner1 class but I want to do `each` event on only spinner1 class inside `busket1` class. My above jquery code does not works. I can't re write my own code to fix up this issue. Any idea?

Comment: try $('.busket').find('.spinner1').each(function(){

Comment: you're most welcome :) I've posted my solution. please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes. it is accepted and up voted. But why my question is down voted. its really frustrating to ask question when a question is down voted without any reason.

Comment: i think the reason it was down voted was this was an easy question which you could have easily googled and found the answer to.. this is what i think. I am not sure what the down voter was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do it like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('.busket').find('.spinner1').each(function() {
      alert('it works');
    });
});
```

this way, it will find all the elements with class `spinner1` inside `busket`